# Can phonegap app which uses webgl be published on play.google

Tags: cordova, webgl, cordova-2.0.0

I want to learn webgl and want to create simple phonegap/webgl game ( there is plugin for webgl for phonegap) and want to put free for android or another, just to get feedback
Did anyone put phonegap app which uses webgl on [play.google](https://play.google.com/store) or another web markets?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
webgl is supported on iOS 8 and greater using both UIWebView or WKWebView

OLD ANSWER:
As far as I know there is no webgl plugin for phonegap (well, there is one but it ins't finished, it seems more like a proof of concept)

If you mean project crosswalk that isn't a plugin, it's a complete webview with phonegap API support, but it's for android only.

I think the only way to run webgl games on both iOS and android is using another webview, like the mentioned [project crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) (android only), [cocoonjs](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/), or webgl implementation [ejecta](http://impactjs.com/ejecta)

And of course you can publish your apps on the stores using any o this options